# Create a batch file to run an .exe with an additional parameter

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need a batch file which will do the following:

```
1. Open CMD and navigate to a location C:/Users/...../program.exe
2. Run the program.exe with an additional command to point it to a config file:
e.g. "program.exe C:/Users/..../configFile.bgi"
```

How can I do this?

I tried this but with no luck:

```
start "C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\BGInfo\bginfo.exe C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\BGInfo\dc_bginfo.bgi"
pause
```

**Update**

I've used the solution provided by Ganesh (below) and came up with this:

```
cd C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\BGInfo\
bginfo.exe C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\BGInfo\dc_bginfo.bgi
```

I've tested it on a local machine (changing the directories) but on the server (with the directory above) it does not work...

The folder directory with batch file:
[image]

The error
[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

in batch file abc.bat

```
cd c:\user\ben_dchost\documents\
executible.exe -flag1 -flag2 -flag3
```

I am assuming that your `executible.exe` is present in `c:\user\ben_dchost\documents\`
I am also assuming that the parameters it takes are  `-flag1` `-flag2` `-flag3`

Edited:

For the command you say you want to execute, do:

```
cd C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\BGInfo\
bginfo.exe dc_bginfo.bgi
pause
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Just tested it on a remote server and it doesn't appear to like the script (I'm in process of editing my question so you can see what I've done)

Comment: if you have spaces in your path\filename, you have to enclose it in double quotes. Else `cd c:\program files\whatever` will try to change to `c:\program` which doesn't exist.

Comment: i tried creating a `.bat` file with the contents
`cd E:\XXXX\Installers\blender\blender-3.1.0-windows-7\blender-3.1.0-windows-7\`<br/>
`blender.exe`<br/>
but it does not work. but if i manually go into the folder with file explorer i can open the file. apparently this method does not work on windows 7. But @Mofi method works.

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
start "" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\BGInfo\bginfo.exe" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\BGInfo\dc_bginfo.bgi"
```

or

```
start "" /D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\BGInfo" bginfo.exe dc_bginfo.bgi
```

or

```
"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\BGInfo\bginfo.exe" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\BGInfo\dc_bginfo.bgi"
```

or

```
cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\BGInfo"
bginfo.exe dc_bginfo.bgi
```

Help on commands **start** and **cd** is output by executing in a command prompt window `help start` or `start /?` and `help cd` or `cd /?`.

But I do not understand why you need a batch file at all for starting the application with the additional parameter. Create a shortcut (*.lnk) on your desktop for this application. Then right click on the shortcut, left click on **Properties** and append after a space character `"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\BGInfo\dc_bginfo.bgi"` as parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Found another solution for the same. It will be more helpful.

*START C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Test\"Test Automation"\finger.exe ConfigFile="C:\Users\PCName\Desktop\Automation\Documents\Validation_ZoneWise_Default.finger.Config"*

finger.exe is a parent program that is calling config solution.
Note: if your path folder name consists of spaces, then do not forget to add "".

Comment: Yes, `"` are necessary as explained by the help output on running `cmd /?` in a command prompt window. It is necessary to enclose a file or folder or any other argument string containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~<>|`` in `"` to be interpreted as one argument string with these characters interpreted literally. But the entire file/folder name must be enclosed in `"` and not just parts of it. So really correct is `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\Test Automation\finger.exe"` and the posted file name is of incorrect syntax which `cmd.exe` corrects on execution of `start`.

Comment: Learn from `cmd.exe` the correct syntax by using the file name completion of `cmd`. Type in a command prompt window `C:\Pro` and press key __TAB__ and displayed is `"C:\Program Files"`. Press once more key __TAB__ and displayed is `"C:\Program Files (x86)"`. Press again key __TAB__ and displayed is `C:\ProgramData`. Press twice __TAB__ and continue typing after displayed `"C:\Program Files"` with `\Test\Tes` and press key __TAB__. The displayed string changes to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\Test Automation"`. The automatic correction can be seen wonderfully using the file name completion.

Comment: Continue typing with `\fin` and press __TAB__ and there is finally displayed `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\Test Automation\finger.exe"`. That is the correct specified fully qualified file name according to the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). The character `"` is a not allowed character inside a file/folder name as described by Microsoft. This is the reason why `cmd.exe` can detect the syntax error caused by `"` inside a file/folder name string and corrects wrong specified argument string.

Comment: But with using the correct syntax of enclosing entire file name in `"`, the command __START__ interprets now `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\Test Automation\finger.exe"` as optional console window title and the command line without `""` after __START__ does not work anymore without an explicitly specified empty window title string between the command __START__ and the fully qualified file name of the Windows GUI executable to start. It is a bad concept to make use of an invalid syntax and the automatic syntax correction of `cmd` to get a command line working which is in real of invalid syntax.