# How to make batch file to run exe file which requires some text

Tags: batch-file

I need to run 'a.exe'.
When I start 'a.exe' file, a console pops up, and I should type "go", then the program start.

If i want to make a batch file to run this program, how should i make this.
I tried as below:

```
///////////
%~d0
cd %~dp0
start a.exe > "go"
pause
///////////
```

but "go" appears on the batch console, and the "a.exe" program still requires "go" text.

How can i solve this?

Comment: reverse the `>` into a `<`

Comment: `echo "go"|a.exe` or `echo go>go.txt & "a.exe"<"go.txt"`  or `a.exe go` ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are coding a windows .bat script, you can execute any file by just passing the file with its path and its argument on the same line `a.exe go`, so your script would be something like this:

```
@echo off
c:\path\to\file\a.exe go
PAUSE
```

I am turning off CMD echo so the output of **a.exe** is easier to be read.

There is another question here were this is further explained: [Create a batch file to run an .exe with an additional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901042/create-a-batch-file-to-run-an-exe-with-an-additional-parameter).

On the other hand, if you need to call another script, you would need to use the method call

```
@echo off
call c:\path\to\other\script\script.bat
c:\path\to\file\a.exe go
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
start echo go| a.exe
```

Answer (score -2):

Just type in

```
a.exe go
```

Hope it helped you out.

You can also use it to run files through certain programs

```
photoshop img.png
```