# Start a *.exe without window but with *.bat

Tags: batch-file, exe

I want to start a program without a window with a batch file.

The window of the batch file is irrelevant. The window of the program is important!

I haven't found anything with google.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/140047/how-to-run-a-batch-file-without-launching-a-command-window#

Comment: I want to hide the program window, not the batch-window

Comment: If a program isn't designed to be able to run in the background, you can't force it to. You can start it minimized, but you can't necessarily open it "without a window." It really depends on what program you're trying to run.

Comment: If an application doesn't ignore `nCmdShow` from `WinMain` (which many applications do ignore), then its main window can be hidden. notepad is an example that allows this. But a batch script can't implement it since `start` only supports `/min` and `/max` show values.

Comment: Ok, thx for the support!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with "***Start***" command.
For eg)

> START C:\Windows\NOTEPAD.EXE

For more info you may visit [***this***](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001345.htm) site.

If you need to run it with additional parameters ***[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901042/create-a-batch-file-to-run-an-exe-with-an-additional-parameter)*** is some help provided.

Comment: You can explore it under procexp.exe, it will have a tailing blank space afer exe.